# How can I change the NavigationController.title.font on the Storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

Now, I use the `storyboard` to setup the UI. It is a `UITableViewController` in the `storyboard`.  The `UITableViewController` is the `rootViewController` of the `UINavigationController` . Now , I set the `NavigationController`'s title, but the title is too small. I want to change the font of the title and the color of the title. How should I do in the `StoryBoard`. 
   By the way, if it can't do in the `storyBoard`. Can I do it use code ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using StoryBoard see following Image

[image]

**using Code**

Add code in view didload

```
 NSShadow *shadow = [NSShadow new];
[shadow setShadowColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
[shadow setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f)];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimeBurner" size:27.0f], NSFontAttributeName,
                                         [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                         shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,nil]];
```